# How to run a script when install a rpm package?

Tags: rpm

I try to build rpm package. I follow [here](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/linux/linux-build-simple-rpm-packages.php#installation).

I want to run a script (bash or python) when run command as "`rpm -Uvh mytest-1.0-1.el6.noarch.rpm`" .

Could run a script when install a rpm package? How?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [RPM Guide](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora_Draft_Documentation/0.1/html/RPM_Guide/index.html):

[Defining installation scripts:](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora_Draft_Documentation/0.1/html/RPM_Guide/ch09s04s05.html)

> RPM supports a script run prior to installation, %pre, and a script
>   run after installation, %post. The same concepts apply when a package
>   is erased, or uninstalled. The %preun script is run just before the
>   uninstall and the %postun script just after the uninstal

So, use the `%pre` section if you want to run the script right before the package is installed or the `%post` section if you want to run it after the package is installed.

---

See also [Mandriva Howto](http://wiki.mandriva.com/en/Development/Howto/RPM#Of_Pre-_and_Post-installation_scripts), [rpm.org](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-inside-scripts.html)

Answer (score 1):

[Commands run before package install are placed in the `%pre` section. Commands run after package install are placed in the `%post` section.](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora_Draft_Documentation/0.1/html/RPM_Guide/ch09s04s05.html)