# create an RPM so that install will edit a config file using a shell command

Tags: rpm

I have a RPM spec file. How can I make it so that after the RPM installs, a random string is injected into one of the configuration files?

For example:

The RPM installs the binaries and config file to

```
/opt/bin/foo
/opt/bar.cfg
```

Inside the bar.cfg, I have the following configuration.

```
foo.bar = [
        [
                clientId:"herp-derp",
                clientSecret:"<ENTER-CLIENTSECRET-HERE>",
                authorizedGrantTypes:["password"]
        ]
]
```

I want the RPM's that are distributed to replace `"<ENTER-CLIENTSECRET-HERE>"` with an actual random string.

Here is how I am generating the random string

echo `cat /dev/urandom | base64 | tr -dc "[:alnum:]" | head -c32`

Since I have never worked much with RPM or spec files in the past, I'm not sure the appropriate way to go about this. Can I just add something like this to the spec file?

```
%post
RANDOM_STRING=`cat /dev/urandom | base64 | tr -dc "[:alnum:]" | head -c32`
sed -i.bak "s/clientSecret:\"<ENTER-CLIENTSECRET-HERE>\",/clientSecret:\"$RANDOM_STRING\",/g" /opt/bar.cfg
```

Comment: see here for how to do pre and post scripts http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/76803/how-to-run-a-script-when-install-a-rpm-package?rq=1